# Adding to an Array List not summing

Tags: java, arrays

Need some help adding to the first array I created named FTGames. When i run this it shows the number in brackets. for example. I start with 1 it displays Game [1]. for game 2 it displays Game [1,1], and so on as I add. I cant seem to figure out #1 how to get rid of the [] on the display or print out. And #2 how do I get it to add the increase instead of listing it as a separate int. I have labeled the areas that are in question. Im sure this is an easy fix that I am overlooking.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Final {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create # of games played array
    List<Integer> FTGames = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    FTGames.add(1);
        // create # of shots made array
    List<Integer> ShotsMade = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
        // Create scanner for user percentage input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int percent = input.nextInt();
                                // FTGames shows []      in this run
    System.out.println("Game" + FTGames + ":");
    Random r = new Random();
    FTGames.add(1); // Adds 1 to FTGames
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
        if (in) {
        ShotsMade.add(1);
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        }
        else {
        ShotsMade.add(0);
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        }
    }
                        // FTGames shows [1] in this run
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Game" + FTGames + ":");
    FTGames.add(1); //Adds 1 to FTGames to make this Game 2 ** But is not showing that **
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
        if (in) {
        ShotsMade.add(1);
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        }
        else {
        ShotsMade.add(0);
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        }
    }
                        // FTGames shows [1,1}
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Game" + FTGames + ":");
    FTGames.add(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
        if (in) {
        ShotsMade.add(1);
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        }
        else {
        ShotsMade.add(0);
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        }
    }


}




public static boolean tryFreeThrow(int percent) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int number = r.nextInt(100);
    if (number > percent){ 
     return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you understand what `.add()` does.

Calling `.add()` adds elements to the list. So if you have a list called `myList` and you call `myList.add(1)` it becomes `[1]`. Then when you do `myList.add(2)` to it, it doesn't do arithmetic, it adds the new element to the end of the list and the list becomes `[1, 2]`.

If I understand your problem correctly what you want to do is something like: Doing `myList.add(1)` should give you the list as `[1]` but adding 1 to it should change that very element, as in do arithmetic on it, and result in `[2]`. In this case what you would do is something like this:

```
myList.set(0, 1+1); // just an example to clarify, you want to avoid having random numbers and arithmetic without any explanation
```

The `set()` method in this example takes `0` which is the index of the element and the second argument is an `Integer` which in this case is `1+1` which results in `2`. When you print this out, you will get `[2].

To get rid of the `[]`, instead of doing

```
System.out.println(myList);
```

do:

```
System.out.println(myList.get(0));
```

This will get you only the first element of the list. Seeing that you are only changing the first element of the list, this should be sufficient (with the formatting and what not added as you see fit).

Lastly, I would **strongly** suggest you look at the documentation because without the documentation you will not be able to learn all that much.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

**UPDATE**

Here's what your `main()` method would look like if you actually implemented code suggested by me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create # of games played array
    List<Integer> FTGames = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    FTGames.add(1);
    // create # of shots made array
    List<Integer> ShotsMade = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
    // Create scanner for user percentage input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int percent = input.nextInt();
    // FTGames shows []      in this run
    System.out.println("Game " + FTGames.get(0) + ":");
    Random r = new Random();
    FTGames.set(0, FTGames.get(0)+1); // Adds 1 to FTGames
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
        if (in) {
            ShotsMade.add(1);
            System.out.print("In" + " ");
        }
        else {
            ShotsMade.add(0);
            System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        }
    }
    // FTGames shows [1] in this run
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Game " + FTGames.get(0) + ":");
    FTGames.set(0, FTGames.get(0)+1); //Adds 1 to FTGames to make this Game 2 ** But is not showing that **
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
        if (in) {
            ShotsMade.add(1);
            System.out.print("In" + " ");
        }
        else {
            ShotsMade.add(0);
            System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        }
    }
    // FTGames shows [1,1}
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Game " + FTGames.get(0) + ":");
    FTGames.set(0, FTGames.get(0)+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
        if (in) {
            ShotsMade.add(1);
            System.out.print("In" + " ");
        }
        else {
            ShotsMade.add(0);
            System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Once again I would suggest reading the documentation and actually understanding what the code is doing. To that end, if you are confused about anything that I have changed in your code, ask me here. I'd be happy to explain it to you.

**UPDATE 2**

I have explained all of this so you would understand what you were doing wrong with `add()` and how, if you needed to, you could perform arithmetic operations on (or change values of) elements within a list. However, for this purpose I would suggest a simple counter. Something simple like:

```
int myGameCounter = 1;
```

And later whenever you want to represent more games played by adding 1, you can do:

```
myGameCounter++;
```

Comment: I tried this and now get an error when trying to run. Indexoutofbounds. Index 0: Size 0: I added the myList.set(0,1+1); in the main. Thanks fro the info on getting rid of the [], that worked great.

Comment: @user3467373 Okay, but `myList` is a name I made up. In your program this would be `FTGames`...

Comment: In main after i defined the list, i added "FTGames.set(0,1+1); to set the first value and it is now giving that error. I had assumed that would set FTGames [0],[0] to [0],[1], and then when i did the FTGames.add(1) change that to [0],[2] and display accordingly.

Comment: @user3467373 Give me a second, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @user3467373 See my update. It is working as you wanted it in your question. It adds the number and it doesn't have the `[]`.

Comment: I added it to the wrong spot that is why. I put it towards the top after I listed List<Integer> FTGames= new ArrayList<Integer>();.   Thanks that makes more sense now.

Comment: @user3467373 No problem. Happy to help and let me know if you want me to explain anything to you from the changes I made to your code in my update.

Comment: So looking over it basically whit the add, It is forcing the element to be set to 0 and then adding 1 to it. So after running it say 4 times, how does it increment to 4?

Comment: @user3467373 `FTGames.set(0, FTGames.get(0)+1);` line gets the first element (the only element in your list) using `.get(0)` and adds 1 to it. It keeps doing that as many times as you execute this line. So if you run it 4 times, it will have the first statement which `add`s 1 to the list, then keeps performs additions on that 1 three more times resulting in a 4.

Comment: @user3467373 Also see **UPDATE 2** in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So if i change the (0) to (1) that would get the 2nd element in the the list? The reason i ask is for the shotsMade i will log up to 10 in or out shots ex [1,1,1,1 etc] for every made shot in that game. And if i change the (0) to (1) that would allow me to use the data from the 2nd game? So i can call them later to sum or average.

Comment: I tried a counter first before i posted this, that is also what the first person who replied to this made me realize. But the counter once repeated gave me a compiling error.

Comment: @user3467373 Precisely. changing `(0)` to `(1)` gets you the 2nd element, and so on. There are two methods here that I am referring to: `get(0)` gets you the first element. `get(1)` gets you the second element, etc. Similarly, `set(0,...)` changes the value of the first element, `set(1,...)` changes the value of the second element, etc.

Comment: So for example the first game I want to shotsMade.set(0, ShotsMade(0)+1); and that will add 1 everytime the boolean runs and "True" or In is made. So at the end of that game I can the call a println to show me the total of element [0]. Then in the 2nd game use shotsMade.set(1, shotsMade.get(1)+10; to fill the value for that game. I could then sum the 2 elements. I hope that that is right, I understand the logic but not sure if thats the right way to express. I was going to use a 2d so row can be game and cloumn the 10 shots.

Comment: @user3467373 Yes the logic and the code seems fine. You will have to deal with making sure `True` or `In` is `1` and `False` or `Out` is `0`. You also need to make sure that for each new game then you do `shotsMade.add(1)` or `shotsMade.add(0)` depending on whether the first shot in that game was `In` or `Out`. If you don't do `add()` at the start of every game you won't actually have added elements to `shotsMade`. I would implement what you understand now and if you hit a wall open a new question regarding that aspect of your game.

Comment: @ Nicolas Carlo Thank you very much for your help. You have saved me hours of time.

Comment: @user3467373 No problem at all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

On a side note it isn't really the done thing in java to name variables with a capital letter  (eg FTGames and ShotsMade, the usual convention is lowerCamelCase, types should be UpperCamelCase )

Your FTGames variable is a list. When you toString a list it helpfully displays the contents of the list in [] and comma separated, so when you are seeing

```
[1,1]
```

This is your list `FTGames` with 2 elements in it. When you call FTGames.add(1) this means add another integer to the list with the value of `1`

Presumably instead of adding a new game with a value of `1` you want to run another iteration of your game?

So what you are doing wrong is expecting `.add()` to perform some kind of integer addition when what it actually does it adds another element to a list. Have a think about the correct types to use for this particular problem

- the number of shots made per game
- the results for the number of games run

I'm not going to do your homework for you but using 2 lists like you are at the moment is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, @stringy05, I was not looking for anyone to do the work, just point me in the right direction. Yes, i need the game to run 5 times total. I now looking at it know i need to create a 2D array for the shotsMade so it can be [5][10] so i can have each shot log in the row for game and column for the shot. So later i can use that data to sum and average. But for the game count I thought this would be cleaner then just using a straight counter. I appear to be wrong. If i am off base please let me know. Also I haven't yet found a way to set this up to run 1 time and then call it x amount.

Comment: I dont think you need a 2d array. Try a single array to keep track of the games with the list element representing the result for that iteration. eg a list of games [5,6,4,5,10] where these ints represent the number of shots made. The index of the element tells you which game number it was

Comment: but when i print it out currently it only shows [1,1,1,1 etc ] for each shot made. So it countinually tallies them. How can I get it to total for each element. Isnt the index only going to display the element in what ever i call ex. shotsMade[8], that will be the 8th element that was added from either the 1st or maybe 2nd game.

Comment: Dont store an array of the shots made for the current game. ok this is the only specific hint I'm going to give you - shotsmade should be an int and it should be used to tally the number of shots per iteration.

Comment: if I make shotsMade be a counter to tally the In shots. That will yield me a total, then i can store that value to an array to use later? I did try to use a counter but for each game I had to label intCounter1, intCounter2, since they are all in the main and it was causing it to not compile since you cant repeat.